# Using ImageMagick/ZBar to read QR codes

Tags: imagemagick, zbar

I've got scanned image files that I perform some preprocessing on and get them looking something like this:

[image: QR Code Image]

My phone's ZBar app can read this QR code fine, but `zbarimg` seems to be unable to figure it out. I've tried all sorts of things in ImageMagick to make it smoother (`-smooth`, `-morphology`) but even with slightly better-looking results, `zbarimg` still comes up blank.

Why would my phone's ZBar be so much better than my computer's (`zbar-0.10`)? Is there anything I can do to get `zbarimg` to read this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try morphological closing.

Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import qrtools
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgPath = "Fdnm1.png"

img = cv2.imread(imgPath, 0)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
processed=cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('test.png', processed)
d = qrtools.QR(filename='test.png')
d.decode()
print d.data
```

Result:

```
1MB24
```